# How could I build on one of multiple entries with webpack

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, multiple-entries, commonschunkplugin

with webpack ,we can build multiple entries just like below:

````
```
{
       entry:{
         'a':'a.js',
         'b':'b.js'
       },
       ...
       plugins:[
          new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
            name:'vendor',
            minChunks:Infinity
            }),

       ]
    }
```
````

we can Generate an extra chunk, which contains common modules shared between entry points.when I have a lot entries,I just change the a.js,I only want to rebuild a.js,But the vendor.js and b.js should not change,how could I did this?

Answer (score 0):

You may want rewrite you config like this

````
```
{
       entry:{
         'a':'a.js',
         'b':'b.js'
       },
       ...
       plugins:[
          new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
            name:'vendor'
            }),
          new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
            name:'manifest',
            chunks: 'vendor',
            minChunks: Infinity
            }),

       ]
    }
```
````